# python os.popen does not work with a command that works in cmd prompt

Tags: python, popen

I am able to run the following using os.popen

```
x = os.popen('dir')
```

but the following does not work

```
x = os.popen('cmd /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\Tcl\8.4.14.0\bin\wish84.exe" "C:/Users/lab/Documents/Public/TCL/Scripts/GetStatsFirst2.tcl""')
```

I have run the exact command on the windows command line, and it manages to open the TCL wish console and does everything.  It just doesn't work with os.popen.  It is supposed to open a TCL wish console, run the script and close.  Is there a way to make this work?

Also, I have tried subprocess.call with this command and it returns 1 and does nothing.

```
subprocess.call(['cmd', '/C', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ixia\Tcl\8.4.14.0\bin\wish84.exe', 'C:/Users/lab/Documents/Public/TCL/Scripts/GetStatsFirst2.tcl'], shell = False)
```

Comment: Why are you using the deprecated and obsolete `os.popen` function in the first place? Show what you attempted with `subprocess.call` and maybe we can fix it for you. (My first guess is that you forgot `shell=True`.)

Comment: Also, why are you even trying to run `cmd` through the shell? `cmd` is _already_ the shell. What happens if you just run wish84 itself through the shell? Does it not work?

Comment: Another thing:  `"\b" == "\x08"`.  Watch our for string escapes.  Using a raw (`r"..."`) string is the easiest way to avoid have backslashes doing unexpected things.

Comment: Hi Tim, your input is correct and solved the problem.  Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: @user442920 I still didn't get what Tim said. Can you please elaborate on that ?